How to sync dropdown changes across multiple Google Sheets?
I'm working on a project in Google Sheets where I need a consistent color dropdown list across multiple sheets. The source data for the dropdown (text and corresponding colors) is stored in a separate hidden sheet named "Data", like this:

I've successfully created the dropdown using Data Validation with the "List from a range" option, referencing 'Data'!A2:A1000. However, the dropdown doesn't show the colors from the Data sheet.
Here is an image illustrates the desired outcome:

My idea is to write a function that:

Iterates through each cell in the relevant range of the Data sheet.
Extracts the cell's fill color and text.
Sets the corresponding item in the dropdown list to have that color.

Here's a pseudocode concept:
foreach column in sheet(dataSheet):
  foreach row in column:
    colour = getFilledColour(column, row);
    text   = getText(column, row);
    setDropDownItemColour(column, text, colour);

Unfortunately, I'm struggling to implement this in Google Apps Scripts.
Is this approach feasible? Are there any built-in Google Sheets features or other techniques I could leverage to achieve this?
